# I can fetch data but when im not using the app after 1-2days, fetching data not working anymore. (Flutter)

Tags: api, http, flutter

//Am i doing wrong way?
Im fetching the data at first but after 1-2days of not using the app, fetching data is not working anymore.

```
Future<List<TopCourses>> fetchTopCourseList() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');
    final response = await client.get(
      URL_STUDENT_GET_TOP_COURSES,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400) {
      throw Exception('Failed to Load');
    } else {
      return compute(topcourseFromJson, response.body);
    }
  }
List<TopCourses> topcourseFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return new List<TopCourses>.from(
      jsonData["top"].map((x) => TopCourses.fromJson(x)));
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: 'Failed to Load'. But when I try to clear the data of my app, fetching data is working again. For the mean time that's the temporary solution to make the fetch data work.

Comment: But I dont want to clear the data of app. Because it will take me to login page again coz of token.

Comment: where you storing data in SharedPreferences. I think you calling `pref.setString();` without checking null condition. I mean to store data in a particular key only if it does not contain any value.

Comment: im storing my token to sharedpreferences when logging in and removing it when logging out.

Comment: Sounds like your access token is expired. What's the status code when it fails?

Comment: Ya, right it may possible @Jordan Davies.

Comment: Good but store data before checking null condition don't call it every time. @fitzpatrickyanes

Comment: I guess the token expiration is my problem. I set it to 1 day. Thank you guys for helping me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your **`accessToken`** has expired, or the **`accessToken`** you're trying to get from **`SharedPreferences`** has been wiped from your app data.

- trying checking that your access token is not null
- and the token has not to expired